# Angular Jest service test fail if service has a contructor

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

Angular test fail when i try to test service that contains contructor. No matter if constructor has dependencies or it's empty.

Hi, I have an issue with testing angular app using jest. When I try to test my service i receive error:

```
 <dirToProject>\src\app\core\services\simple.service.ts:8
        static { this.ctorParameters = () => []; }
               ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

    > 1 | import { SimpleService } from './simple.service';
        | ^
      2 | import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
      3 |
      4 | describe('SimpleService', () => {

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1495:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/core/services/simple.service.spec.ts:1:1)
```

Simple service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SimpleService {

  constructor() { }
}
```

Test:

```
import { SimpleService } from './simple.service';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('SimpleService', () => {
  let service: SimpleService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = new SimpleService();
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Surprisingly this error disappear when i delete constructor from service. Of course in this example I can remove contructor, but I have to test more complex services with dependencies.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?
Versions: `"jest": "^29.5.0", "@angular/core": "^15.2.0"`

Comment: Angular is using Dependency Injection.  Does your constructor have injections?  If so, you need to provide these in the test file, similar to the module definitions (providers) to have the test framework perform the dependency injection.

Comment: @StevenScott No my contructor is empty as i showed in example

Answer (score 0):

@Alokin try setting up the tsconfig.ts or tsconfig.spec.ts `"target": "ES2020"` or if you use `"target": ES2022` set to true the `useDefineForClassFields` property

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The reason was that static initialization blocks are a feature introduced in Node 16, and I had Node 14.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Static_initialization_blocks#browser_compatibility

I upgraded Node from 14 to 20 and the problem disappeared.